# What if i don't use index fields in my program?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I am a beginner to this progress 4GL. I have confused with the following logic especially how the index actually working.

I have added 2 fields in one index. As you can see below I have written three queries.

Query 1, Used the index and finding data from 2 fields to retrieve the data

Query 2, Used the same index but finding data from 1 field only

Query 3, Used the same index field with one non-index field

```
define temp-table tt_creldata no-undo
field tt_cscx_order    as character 
field tt_cscx_part     as character
field tt_cscx_shipfrom as character
index tt_cscx
      tt_cscx_order
      tt_cscx_part
.
**Query 1:**
find first tt_creldata use-index tt_cscx 
      where tt_cscx_order = "153" 
      and tt_cscx_part = "113" no-lock no-error.

**Query 2:**
find first tt_creldata use-index tt_cscx 
       where tt_cscx_order = "153" no-lock no-error.

**Query 3:**
find first tt_creldata use-index tt_cscx
      where tt_cscx_order = "153" 
      and tt_cscx_part = "113" 
      and tt_cscx_shipfrom = "US" no-lock no-error.
```

Question 1: Which query helps to improve the performance

Question 2: What if I don't use one field which is indexed when I mentioned use-index

Question 3: What if I add one non-index field when I mentioned use-index?

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule of thumb, you should never use `use-index`.

The AVM will select one or more indexes to use for a query at compile time, and by forcing it to use one of your choosing, you are removing the possibility of this.

Having extra, possibly non-index, fields in your where clause will only affect the indexes chosen if you let the AVM choose (ie don't use `use-index` ). This is also true if you don't use indexed fields in your query.

You can see which indexes are used if you compile the program with the [`xref`](https://docs.progress.com/bundle/openedge-abl-troubleshoot-applications-117/page/COMPILE-XREF-option.html) or `xml-xref` options, and looking for the `SEARCH` items.

Answer (score 1):

As nwahmaet says, you should never use USE-INDEX. In this case it is especially pointless because there is only one index. In cases where there are multiple indexes a FIND statement will only use one of them no matter how complex the WHERE clause but the compiler will almost always do a better job picking an efficient index than you will. (The FOR EACH statement and its associated dynamic queries are capable of using multiple indexes. FIND is always limited to just one index.) In those rare cases where you think you are doing a better job you should thoroughly document why your choice is better and include detailed test cases and results.

All of your queries are using FIRST. This is necessary because your index is not defined as unique. That may be your intent but it seems unusual. And it means that in the event of duplicate records with the same key values you are magically making the "first" record more special than the others. Which is a data normalization faux pas (you are making "firstness" an attribute of the data) and a bug waiting to happen.

FIND FIRST and USE-INDEX are often used together to (try to) cover up for each other's deficiencies. By specifying a particular index the FIRST becomes more consistent. Likewise, FIRST is often used to "cure" performance issues that arise from insufficient index definitions, inadequate WHERE clauses or choosing FIND when FOR EACH would have been more appropriate.

None of these queries are going to perform notably faster than the others.

Query 2 may, or may not return the same record as query 1. For instance, if there is a part = "112" then query 2 will have a different "first" record. But it will be just as fast to return as query 1.

Likewise query 3 may have a different result depending on what records contain shipfrom = "US". In the best case where the very first order = "153" and part "113" also satisfy shipfrom = "US" then it will be the same speed as the others.

However, query 3 ***might*** be a lot slower depending on how many records have to be scanned before one is found that has shipfrom = "US" since that field is not a part of any index and matching it will, therefore, require scanning records until one is found which matches. That might be the first record or it might be the 10 zillionth.